# Persistent Blocking Queue in Java?

Tags: java, concurrency, persistent-storage, blockingqueue

**TL;DR; I need to know if there's a lib with persistent blocking queue that performatic.**

I hava a classic producer/consumers program. They share a `LinkedBlockingQueue` to share the data, and I use `BlockingQueue#take` method in the Consumers, as I need them to live forever waiting for new elements.

The problem is I have LOTS of data and I can't lose them. Even after the consumers stops, the producer can persist to generate some data. I am thinking about implementing my BlockingQueue ta uses `H2` behind to store/get the data after some threshold is reached. My main problem is that I need performance and I need to consume the elements in the order they are created.

Is there an implementation of persistent blocking queue that I can use for something like this? If it doesn't, any sugestions for me to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use ActiveMQ lib and Spring JMS, here is a usage example

start broker

```
BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
broker.addConnector("tcp://localhost:61616");
broker.start();
```

read msg

```
ConnectionFactory cf = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");
JmsTemplate t = new JmsTemplate(cf);
Message msg = t.receive();
```

send message

```
ConnectionFactory cf = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");
JmsTemplate t = new JmsTemplate(cf);
t.send("test", new MessageCreator() {
  public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
    return session.createTextMessage("test");
  }
});
```

Comment: I can't use spring, because it's an old software :/ Anyway, does JMS persists the Queue? Didn't know that. Don't I need to register a topic?

Comment: 1) Spring is just for convinience, you can work directly with JMS. 2) It's not JMS but Messaging Provider like ActiveMQ who persists messages, the message sender decides whether a message should be persisted or not when it sends it, there is a parameter - DeliveryMode

Answer (score 3):

You can try [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/).  The ActiveMQ can write to your file system so if the producer is generating many more elements than the consumer can take you either have a lot of blocking (on whatever the upper bound of the queue is) or excessive data (if there is no upper bound to the queue).

Comment: but does it guarantee order?

Answer (score 1):

Have you come across [Amazon SQS](http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/) its an unbounded queue and very fast, It guarantees order.How long do you want to persist the data for?

Comment: I need it for an intranet, but thanks for the answer :D Didn't know SQS

Answer (score 0):

You can use any JMS implementation for supporting excess incoming data. This is a producer consume problem and jms is designed for this.